# Увеличение потребления памяти

Tags: golang

Начинаю изучать язык Go. Не могу понять почему растет потребление памяти. Не срабатывает сборщик мусора? Горутины же выполняются и завершаются.

```
package main

import (
"time"
)

const kol = 5

func parsePage(c chan <-string, page string) {

time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)

c <- "Fin"
}

func main() {
c := make(chan string, kol)

i := 0

for {

    for i := 0; i < kol; i++ {
        go parsePage(c, "exa")
    }

    for i := 0; i < kol; i++ {
        //fmt.Println(i, " ", <-c)
        <-c
    }

    i++

    time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)

}

}
```

Comment: Как замеряли? У меня со включённым [`expvar`](https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/) память растёт только до сборки мусора, после чего уменьшается и опять начинает расти, как положено.

Comment: Измерял диспетчером задач Windows 10x64. В начале было 1 мб. Через пару минут уже 2 мб и увеличивалось с течением времени (оставлял и на 5 минут).

Comment: запустите с уменьшенными слипами и с `GOGC=10`, например, или меньше. Увидите, как сборка мусора работает. И вообще, диспетчер задач - тот ещё инструмент для сборки подобной информации. Используйте тот же `expvar`.

Comment: Благодарю. Разобрался.